# Confused console.log is outputting a sorted array before the sort operates on it

Tags: javascript, arrays

Baffled as to why both console.logs output a sorted array. It's as if both console.log lines are being run at the end of the script. I was expecting the first console.log to output the unsorted array!? If I comment out the sort the array appears unsorted in the initial console output.

```
const notes=[
    {title: '2. My Next Trip', 
     body: 'I would like to go to Spain...'}, 
    {title: '3. Habits to Work On', 
     body: 'Exercise. Eating a bit better'}, 
    {title: '1. Office meditation', 
     body: 'Get a new seat'}
]
 
console.log(`Unsorted Array : `, notes)

notes.sort((a, b)=>{
    if(a.title < b.title) return -1
    else if(a.title > b.title) return 1
    else return 0
})
 
console.log(`Sorted Array : `, notes)
```

[image]

Comment: It's logging the array by reference so after the sort is done, both logs will display the same, try `console.log(\`Unsorted Array : \`, notes.slice());`.

Comment: It is not the issue of "by reference". The surprise is that the lines of code are not executed in sequence, at least those lines related to `console.log`. If things were run sequentially, the reference to the array at the time of the first `console.log` would have pointed to the unsorted array.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce in Node.js.

Since you're doing this in the browser there's a chance that before the `console.log` object exploder can handle displaying your object you've already sorted it, as those can happen out of sequence.

Try making a copy first, then sorting:

```
sorted = [ ...notes ];

notes.sort(...)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Answer (score 0):

It is because `sort` modified the array and the console reflects changes on the array when displaying it. You can see the difference if you use `JSON.stringify` on the array when logging it. In fact, stack snippets will also show the difference, as it does not dynamically apply changes on objects.

```js
const notes=[
    {title: '2. My Next Trip', 
     body: 'I would like to go to Spain...'}, 
    {title: '3. Habits to Work On', 
     body: 'Exercise. Eating a bit better'}, 
    {title: '1. Office meditation', 
     body: 'Get a new seat'}
]
 
console.log(`Unsorted Array : `, notes)

notes.sort((a, b)=>{
    if(a.title < b.title) return -1
    else if(a.title > b.title) return 1
    else return 0
})
 
console.log(`Sorted Array : `, notes)
```

You could also make a shallow copy of the array to sort using `slice`.

```
const sorted = notes.slice().sort((a, b)=>{
    if(a.title < b.title) return -1
    else if(a.title > b.title) return 1
    else return 0
})
 
console.log(`Sorted Array : `, sorted);
```